# why is cassandra not getting connected to server?

Tags: cassandra

I have installed cassandra and worked on it. It worked properly. Now, it is showing as-

`localhost/<> is in use by another process.  Change listen_address:storage_port in cassandra.yaml to values that do not conflict with other services
Fatal configuration error; unable to start server.  See log for stacktrace.
INFO  09:17:02 Announcing shutdown
INFO  09:17:02 Compacted 4 sstables to [./../data/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/system-local-ka-33,].  6,485 bytes to 5,751 (~88% of original) in 223ms = 0.024595MB/s.  4 total partitions merged to 1.  Partition merge counts were {4:1, }
INFO  09:17:04 Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
user@inblrlt-user:~/dev/Cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.1.7/bin$ ./cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None',)})`

How to change my server address so that the issue is cleared?

Answer (score 1):

Your localhost is already in use. Follow the following steps-

`$ jps`

You see some processes running. For example:

`9107 Jps
1112 CassandraDaemon`

Then kill the `CassandraDaemon` process by the process id you see after executing `jps`. In my example, here process id `1112` for `CassandraDaemon`.

`$ kill -9 1112`

Then check processes again after a while-

`$ jps`

You will see `CassandraDaemon` will no longer be available.

`9170 Jps`

Then remove your `saved_caches` and `commilog` and start `cassandra` again.

If you want to change the **listen_address** from **localhost** to any private ip or public ip, you need to make the following changes:

1. change **seeds:** at cassandra.yaml
2. change **listen_address:** at cassandra.yaml
3. change **rpc_address:** at cassandra.yaml
4. set `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<place_your_ip_here>"` at cassandra-env.sh

Comment: Before this output, I stopped the running cassandra using ctrl+z and exit. Is this some reason for the result?

Comment: Whenever you feel problem with starting cassandra or any node down issue, you can check logs from- /dev/Cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.1.7/logs/system.log